# AttributeError: 'numpy.ufunc' object has no attribute '__module__' for skimage dependencies

Tags: python, scikit-image

Currently I am working on Ubuntu 16.04 for handwritten character recognition. I am using skimage dependency on **python `2.7.12`**, and when I execute these lines as shown in the image below, I am getting `**AttributeError: 'numpy.ufunc' object has no attribute '__module__'.**` Can anyone help me with this issue?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9n0e.jpg)

Comment: Please post your relevant code & the full error message; see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I am having similar error. I have latest scikit-image 0.14.1 and latest numpy 1.16.0. I am getting this error when I try to import skimage module in python. I am on mac OS.

Comment: Use `scikit-image 0.12.2` which is not throwing this error. I tested for `Python 2.7.15`, I have latest `numpy 0.16` working on mac OS. I think versions of scikit-image > 0.12.2 are not compatible with latest numpy. Use `pip install scikit-image==0.12.2` to install specific version of `scikit-image`.

Comment: you may downgrade exisiting `numpy` to older version `1.15.4` and then latest `scikit-image 0.15.1` is working fine

Comment: but I'm working on Ubuntu 16.04, where I still get the same error after I tried changing the scikit-image and numpy versions